# Unsure how to handle exception in hot potato game C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, exception, int

I'm making a hot-potato game in C#. In the code I was trying to handle an exception in the Game() method where it will prompt you to pass the potato to someone (by their player number) it would prevent you from entering your own player number (trying to pass it to yourself.)
The only thing is, I'm having trouble trying to handle the exception:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HotPotatoe
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.Write("How many players are there? (up to 4): ");
            string PlayerCount = Console.ReadLine();
            string PlayerOne = null;
            string PlayerTwo = null;
            string PlayerThree = null;
            string PlayerFour = null;
            if (PlayerCount == "2")
            {
                Console.Write("Enter player 1's name: ");
                PlayerOne = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter player 2's name: ");
                PlayerTwo = Console.ReadLine();
                Random ran = new Random();
                int WhoStarts = ran.Next(1, 2);
                Game(PlayerOne, PlayerTwo, PlayerThree, PlayerFour, WhoStarts);
            }
            else if (PlayerCount == "3")
            {
                Console.Write("Enter player 1's name: ");
                PlayerOne = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter player 2's name: ");
                PlayerTwo = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter player 3's name: ");
                PlayerThree = Console.ReadLine();
                Random ran = new Random();
                int WhoStarts = ran.Next(1, 3);
                Game(PlayerOne, PlayerTwo, PlayerThree, PlayerFour, WhoStarts);
            }
            else if (PlayerCount == "4")
            {
                Console.Write("Enter player 1's name: ");
                PlayerOne = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter player 2's name: ");
                PlayerTwo = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter player 3's name: ");
                PlayerThree = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter player 4's name: ");
                PlayerFour = Console.ReadLine();
                Random ran = new Random();
                int WhoStarts = ran.Next(1, 4);

                Game(PlayerOne, 
                    PlayerTwo, 
                    PlayerThree, 
                    PlayerFour, 
                    WhoStarts);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not valid!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Main();
            }
        }

        private static void Game
           (string player1, 
            string player2, 
            string player3, 
            string player4, 
            int whoStarts)     
        {
            Player Player1 = new Player();  
            Player Player2 = new Player();
            Player Player3 = new Player();
            Player Player4 = new Player();
            Player1.Name = player1;         
            Player2.Name = player2;
            Player3.Name = player3;
            Player4.Name = player4;
            Player1.Number = 1;
            Player2.Number = 2;
            Player3.Number = 3;
            Player4.Number = 4;
            Player1.IsOut = false;   
            Player2.IsOut = false;
            if(Player3.Name == null)
            {
                Player3.IsOut = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Player3.IsOut = false;
            }
            if (Player4.Name == null)
            {
                Player4.IsOut = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Player3.IsOut = false;
            }
            switch (whoStarts)
            {
                case 1:
                    Player1.HasPotatoe = true;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Player2.HasPotatoe = true;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Player3.HasPotatoe = true;
                    break;
                default:    
                    Player4.HasPotatoe = true;
                    break;
            }
            List<Player> PlayingList = new List<Player>
            {
                Player1,
                Player2
            };
            if (Player3.IsOut == false)
            {
                PlayingList.Add(Player3);
            }
            if (Player4.IsOut == false)
            {
                PlayingList.Add(Player4);
            }
            Random rand = new Random();
            int NumOfRounds = rand.Next(1, 10);
            do
            {
                foreach (Player p in PlayingList)
                {
                    if (p.HasPotatoe == true)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Player {0} has the potatoe! Who do you want to pass it to? (by number): ", p.Number);
                        string input = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (input == "1")
                        {
                            PlayingList[0].HasPotatoe = true;
                            NumOfRounds--;
                        }
                        else if (input == "2")
                        {
                            PlayingList[1].HasPotatoe = true;
                            NumOfRounds--;
                        }
                        else if (input == "3")
                        {
                            if (Player3.IsOut == true)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("That person isn't playing! Choose another player!");
                                Console.ReadKey();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                PlayingList[2].HasPotatoe = true;
                                NumOfRounds--;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (input == "4")
                        {
                            if (Player4.IsOut == true)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("That person isn't playing! Choose another player!");
                                Console.ReadKey();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                PlayingList[3].HasPotatoe = true;
                                NumOfRounds--;
                            }
                        }
                        else if(input == p.Number.ToString())    // this is the part i'm having trouble with................................
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0}", p.Number.ToString());
                            Console.WriteLine("You can't pass it to yourself! -_- Choose someone else..." + p.Number.ToString());
                            Console.ReadKey();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } while (NumOfRounds != 0);
            if(Player1.HasPotatoe == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is out! Play again!", Player1.Name);
                Console.ReadKey();
                Main();
            }
            else if(Player2.HasPotatoe == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is out! Play again!", Player2.Name);
                Console.ReadKey();
                Main();
            }
            else if (Player3.HasPotatoe == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is out! Play again!", Player3.Name);
                Console.ReadKey();
                Main();
            }
            else if (Player4.HasPotatoe == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is out! Play again!", Player4.Name);
                Console.ReadKey();
                Main();
            }
        }
    }        

    class Player
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public bool HasPotatoe { get; set; }
        public bool IsOut { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The specific part where the error is:

```
Random rand = new Random();
            int NumOfRounds = rand.Next(1, 10);
            do
            {
                foreach (Player p in PlayingList)
                {
                    if (p.HasPotatoe == true)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Player {0} has the potatoe! Who do you want to pass it to? (by number): ", p.Number);
                        string input = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (input == "1")
                        {
                            PlayingList[0].HasPotatoe = true;
                            NumOfRounds--;
                        }
                        else if (input == "2")
                        {
                            PlayingList[1].HasPotatoe = true;
                            NumOfRounds--;
                        }
                        else if (input == "3")
                        {
                            if (Player3.IsOut == true)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("That person isn't playing! Choose another player!");
                                Console.ReadKey();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                PlayingList[2].HasPotatoe = true;
                                NumOfRounds--;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (input == "4")
                        {
                            if (Player4.IsOut == true)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("That person isn't playing! Choose another player!");
                                Console.ReadKey();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                PlayingList[3].HasPotatoe = true;
                                NumOfRounds--;
                            }
                        }
                        else if(input == p.Number.ToString())  // this is where the problem is...
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0}", p.Number.ToString());
                            Console.WriteLine("You can't pass it to yourself! -_- Choose someone else..." + p.Number.ToString());
                            Console.ReadKey();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } while (NumOfRounds != 0);
```

so basically I say: if(input == p.Number().ToString()) // p.Number() == player's number
then throw the exception. But i'm not sure how to go about that. I've tried converting the integer to a string with the .ToString() method. but it doesn't seem to change anything. I've also tried turning the input into a 32 bit integer with the Int32.Parse(input) method, but still no luck. The result just does something random. For example if I was player two, and I prompt to pass the potato to player two, then it will just write to the console that player 2 has the potato over and over. I'm not sure how to do this right. Any suggestions?

Comment: its not clear what you are asking. Are you asking how to throw an exception. (A real c# execption) or how to handle that exception. Why are you trying to parse int as part of this

Comment: Note: you're using a lot of duplicate code here and fixed variables for players etc. Think for a bit and simplify using a generalized way. If "2" means an index of 1 and "3" an index of 2 I'm sure you can easily generalize that. As well as printing out the number of players etc based on given player count.

Comment: There is too much code here. You need to provide a good [mcve]. Yes, it has to be **complete**. But it also has to be **minimal**. As in, containing _no_ code that is not strictly necessary to demonstrate the _specific_ problem you are asking about. We don't need or want to see all of the code in your program. ...

Comment: ... While you're working on that, keep in mind that there's probably no good reason to throw an exception in this case. The handling of the input should be close enough to the handling of the error that regular language flow control (loop conditions, ifs, whatever) should suffice. It's bad form to use exceptions for normal flow control in a program.

Answer (score 0):

throw an exception is simple.

```
  else if(input == p.Number.ToString())  
    throw new Exception("You cant do that");
```

Maybe your issue is creating your own exceptions to catch them later. Do

```
    public class BadPlayerException: Exception
    {
    }

...

throw new BadPlayerEcxeption():
```

Comment: How would I add an error message to the console? To let the user know that he is attempting to pass the potato to himself?

Comment: @AaronT. You wouldn't use an exception for this. What's wrong with simply outputting a message to say that you can't pass to yourself, and then repeating the loop?

Comment: @AaronT. To clarify: exceptions should be used where a method cannot know the correct way to handle a set of data, or where the data provided would cause an exception or bad behaviour later. In your case, you have all the information you need to handle the problem in-method. If you really want to terminate the game, simply call `return` after outputting the message that you can't pass to yourself.